# SQL performance GROUP BY vs UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I'm getting poor performance using GROUP BY vs UNION. See below

Using GROUP BY, ~ 17 seconds

```
select b.BookTypeKey, count(b.BookKey) 
from Books b
where contains(b.BookTitle, @SearchTerm)
group by b.BookTypeKey
```

Using UNION, ~ 1-2 seconds

```
select '1' as BookTypeKey, count(b.BookKey)
from Books b
where contains(b.BookTitle, @SearchTerm) and b.BookTypeKey = 1

union

select '2' as BookTypeKey, count(b.BookKey)
from Books b
where contains(b.BookTitle, @SearchTerm) and b.BookTypeKey = 2

union

select '3' as BookTypeKey, count(b.BookKey)
from Books b
where contains(b.BookTitle, @SearchTerm) and b.BookTypeKey = 3
```

Any thoughts? Ideally, I'd like to do this without having to use three separate UNION statements. FYI, there are only three "BookTypes" (1,2 and 3)

Comment: Look at the execution plans, and see what the difference is?

Comment: Seems like if you get dramatically better performance one way, you'd use that way instead. Sometimes you need more complex code to get better performance. Beyond that, not sure we can offer specifics without knowing your whole schema or execution plan.

Comment: @Jeremy How do I review the execution plan? I'm using SQL Management Studio 2008

Comment: Have you timed these using multiple runs, to ensure that the difference is not a caching difference?

Comment: Hover your mouse on the buttons to the right of the big red exclamation point, and find the one with the tooltip that reads "Include Actual Execution Plan" then run your query again. You'll get another tab to the right of the results.

Comment: What is the problem with using a union you have already written?  Really 4 lines versus 11 lines.

Comment: @Blam Yes, there really isn't an issue; I'm currently using that solution, I just thought it was poorly written versus using GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  You say that there are only three book types, but are you really sure?  What does this query return:

```
select b.BookTypeKey, count(b.BookKey) 
from Books b
group by b.BookTypeKey;
```

`NULL` would be a *very* important consideration here.  I would expect that the `contains()` would have a significant affect on the performance.  However, both versions of the query would call `contains()` the same number of times -- unless there are more than three values of `BookTypeKey`.  Otherwise, there may be some strange interaction between the `contains()` and the `group by`.

Also, `union all` should have slightly better performance in the second query.

Comment: Yes, it still only returns three values (1,2 and 3) with no NULL values.